# SQL 2 tables always return all rows from 1 table match existing on other

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.

```
Table1
Id
1
2
3
4

    Table2
VehicleId Value Table1Id
    1      t      1
    1      q      2
    3      w      3
    3      e      4
    4      t      1
    5      e      1
    5      f      2
    5      g      4
```

How can I get it so it always returns Id 1-4 of the first table then joins the values if they do exist in table 2.

For Example a result set would be:

```
VehicleId  Value
    1        t
    1        q
    1    
    1  
    3         w
    3         e
    3
    3
```

So I always want all the results returned from table 1 even if there are no values for it in table 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are arising because your Table2 is not really a 'vehicle' table. Because the VehicleId does not uniquely identify a record in that table. This is where all of the confusion is coming from. So to solve that and get your problem to work I did a select distinct on table2 against the values in table 1 (I also did a select distinct for clarity, but it was not necessary.) Hope this helps.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Id INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (VehicleID INT, Value VARCHAR(50), Table1ID INT)

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (1, 't', 1),(1, 'q', 2),(3, 'w', 3),(3, 'e', 4),(4, 't', 1),(5, 'e', 1),(5, 'f', 2),(5, 'g', 4)

SELECT * FROM #Table1
SELECT * FROM #Table2

SELECT  t2.VehicleID, t2.Value
FROM    ( SELECT    t2.VehicleId, t1.Id
          FROM      ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                VehicleId
                      FROM      #Table2 ) t2
                    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT Id
                                 FROM   #Table1 ) t1 ) Base
        LEFT JOIN #Table2 t2
            ON Base.VehicleId = t2.VehicleID
               AND Base.Id = t2.Table1ID
WHERE (Base.VehicleId BETWEEN 1 AND 3)

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how your example output matches the sample data you provided--was it meant to?

But I think all you need is a LEFT JOIN...

```
SELECT Table2.VehicleId, Table2.Value
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id;
```

Comment: It is supposed to always show all 4 id's from table1 for each vehicle. Table 1 is a lookup table. Just using a left join gives me all the Id's from table 1 that aren't being joined to but it does not give me each id from table 1 for every unit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TAB1.Id,
TAB2.VehicleId,
TAB2.Value
FROM Table1 TAB1 LEFT JOIN Table2 TAB2 ON TAB1.Id = TAB2.Table1Id
```

Comment: This only gives me 1 instance of the ID's form table one. As explained in comments from above answer